# Filter Ads in Admob

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I want to filter the Ads. I have followed this instructions

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150172?hl=en&ref_topic=3052991

My question is how to find the Advertiser URL? I don't know the URL

Comment: Check the `networking` tab of you browsers dev tools

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "Networking Tab"??? You mean "Ad Networks tab", right??

Comment: It's here on [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)

Comment: You would use it to track requests from the browser to websites. If you see one that looks like an ad request, try blocking it. Another way would be clicking the `inspect element` button and checking it for some indication of it's origin...

Comment: Thanks but I add admob for my mobile games application. Chrome devTools is for web application, isn't it? So, I can't use it because my application is for mobile.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were making a webapp...